# How to control the execution of a thread with blocking call

Tags: c++, multithreading

Sorry for the title, I couldn't find a one that describes the problem clearly.

Please read the snippet below. There are 2 threads where the first one controls the execution and the second one does the job.

```
std::atomic<bool> m_running;
Process* process; // A thread-safe process implementation

//thread 1
void stop()
{
    m_running = false;

    if( process->isRunning() )
        process->kill(); // process->join() returns as a result of this call
}

//thread 2
void run()
{
    m_running = true;

    while( m_running )
    {
        do_something();

        process->start();
        process->join(); // Blocking call
    }

    m_running = false;   
}
```

I've noticed that if the first thread starts execution while the second thread is busy with the `do_something()`, it will assign `false` to `m_running` and check if the process is running or not. Since the second thread is still in the `do_something()` call, `process->isRunning()` will return `false` and the first thread will return without killing the process.

But second thread will start the process as soon as finishing `do_something()` as opposed to our stop demand.

The first thing that come to my mind is like the following :

```
//thread 2
void run()
{
    m_running = true;

    while( m_running )
    {
        do_something();

        if( m_running )
        {
            // flagged line ...
            process->start();
        }

        process->join(); // Blocking call
    }

    m_running = false;   
}
```

But still it is possible that the whole `stop()` method in thread 1 can start and finish when the second thread is interrupted in flagged line.

So I decided to use a mutex but I'm not sure if everything is OK or not :

```
//thread 1
void stop()
{
    mutex.lock();
    m_running = false;

    if( process->isRunning() )
        process->kill(); // process->join() returns as a result of this call

    mutex.unlock();
}

//thread 2
void run()
{
    m_running = true;

    while( m_running )
    {
        do_something();

        mutex.lock();
        if( m_running )
        {
            process->start();
        }
        mutex.unlock();

        process->join(); // Blocking call
    }

    m_running = false;   
}
```

Comment: Two points:

1. Don't use `mutex` directly, use `std::unique_lock` (this is the correct tool in your case, because you want to explicitly unlock it before the scope ends). RAII is an important idiom to make your code clear and safe.

2. Why the last `m_running = false;` line? We arrive there only if the `while` loop exited which is when `m_running` is `false`.

Comment: To the question: yes, you "bundle" the flag testing and the process creation together. I just don't think you have to keep holding the mutex in thread 1 after setting the flag.

Comment: (And the flag doesn't have to be atomic anymore, as it's protected by the mutex anyway.)

Comment: You're right about the RAII, actually real code uses it. I've translated it  to mutex in order to simplify the psuedo-code. The `m_running = false` at the end of while loop seems unnecessary.

Comment: If you look at the edit history, you will see that I have limited the scope of mutex to setting the flag. But later I guess I wanted to be in the safe zone :)

Comment: While loop still reads the `m_running`. Are you sure that it doesn't have to be atomic ?

Comment: Oops. Correct. Still atomic for this usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it in terms of indivisible transactions.

```
//thread 1
void stop()
{
    m_running = false;

    {
        //This block should happen as a transaction
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(m_mutex);
        if( process->isRunning() )
            process->kill();
    }
}

//thread 2
void run()
{
    m_running = true;
    while( m_running )
    {
        do_something();
        {
            //Since starting this process depends on m_running 
            //which could change anytime since we tested it last,
            //we test it again, and start, this time as another transaction
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(m_mutex);
            if(m_running)
                process->start();
        }
        process->join(); // Blocking call
    }  
}
```

You don't need to bother about protecting `m_running` since its the default  `std::atomic<bool>` which is *sequentially consistent*

Answer (score 1):

Although a more precise answer needs more details on what `isRunning()`, `kill()`, and `join()`, there's a design flaw that's apparent here.

Namely, the `m_running` flag's purpose is overloaded.

A flag like `m_running` typically implements one of two classical design patterns:

1. It is to report the status of a thread in question: whether it is running, or not.

or:

2. It is to control whether the thread in question should run, or stop.

The shown code is attempting to conflate the two design patterns together. And they don't mesh.

If the purpose of `m_running` is to have the thread in question report its current status, then thread 1's `stop()` has no business setting this flag. `m_running` should only be updated by the thread in question, and, indeed, your thread's `run()` sets it to `true` when it begins, and `false` before it returns. But then, `run()` itself has no business checking the value of `m_running` inside the `if` statement. Its only purpose is to report the status of the thread. Not to have the thread do anything.

With this design pattern, `kill()` typically implements some means for terminating the thread's execution, usually by sending a message of some kind to the thread, that tells the thread to wind down. `kill()` would then monitor and wait until the thread obeys, and sets `m_running` to false, indicating that it exited. Or, if this is a joinable thread, `kill()` would join the thread.

Alternatively, `m_running`'s purpose can be to signal the thread to stop what it's doing. But in this situation, the execution thread's `run()` has no business updating `m_running` itself. All a thread typically does in this design pattern, is execute a `while(m_running)` loop, waiting for the next message. The typical process for stopping the thread involves setting `m_running`, and then sending some kind of no-op message to the thread -- the message's only purpose would be to wake up the thread, so it can cycle through the loop and see the updated value of `m_running`.

The shown code is attempting to conflate the two design patterns into a single variable, and it looks to me like that is the fundamental cause of the design problem.

Separate `m_running` into two discrete variables: one to report the state of the thread (if that's needed), and a second variable that's used as part of a reliable mechanism for an orderly shutdown of the thread.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood you correctly. `m_running = false` statement at the end of the `run()` method seems unnecessary, I can remove that. I can also move the `m_running = true` statement ( at the beginning of `run()` ) to the `start()` method ( not mentioned in the question ) before spawning the `run()` thread. That way, I completely adapt your second alternative but my problem is still there. Am i wrong ?

Comment: No, you're not, but that's not all that I said. I also explained that for this design pattern, there needs to be some means for the thread to be notified to wake up and check `m_running`. Just `m_running` is not enough.